# Получение данных из API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios

Необходимо получить JSON строку с стороннего сервера. Для аутентификации на сервере необходимо добавить к запросу заголовок «TMG-Api-Key» со значением «0J/RgNC40LLQtdGC0LjQutC4IQ==».

Использовал axios из react-приложения. Я раньше этим не занимался, но очень понадобилось сделать. Буду признателен, если кто-то направит меня на правильный путь.

Код:

```
checkApi = () => {
    axios
      .get(`http://tmgwebtest.azurewebsites.net/api/textstrings/1`, {
        headers: {
          "TGM-Api-Key": "0J/RgNC40LLQtdGC0LjQutC4IQ==",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

При запросе получаются ошибки:

1. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://tmgwebtest.azurewebsites.net/api/textstrings/1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

2.Error: Network Error at createError (createError.js:16) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

3.xhr.js:177 GET http://tmgwebtest.azurewebsite... tstrings/1 net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Это сервер\браузер запрещает вам с вашего клиентского кода делать запрос. Решения - использовать прокси, ваш или сторонний. Гуглите, что такое CORS

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через `params:{}`

```
axios.get(`http://tmgwebtest.azurewebsites.net/api/textstrings/1`, {
        params:{
         headers: {
          "TGM-Api-Key": "0J/RgNC40LLQtdGC0LjQutC4IQ==",
         },
        },
      })
```